# Using 'git send-mail', but I am getting an error

Tags: macos, git, perl, sendmail

I am trying to use `git send-mail`, but I am getting this error:

> Can't locate Net/SMTP/SSL.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/../Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
>  
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/perl 
>   /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.16 
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at 
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email 
>   line 1232.

I use [Mac OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) recently upgraded from [Mac OS X v10.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion)!!!

Comment: @mpapec how, what do you mean ?

Comment: As it seems you don't have `Net::SMTP::SSL` installed on your system, and including line above into script would tell you that.

Comment: how do I get `NET::SMTP::SSL` for my osx ?

Comment: http://www.macinstruct.com/node/463

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install SSL.

Use [cpanminus](http://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) for working with CPAN modules. You can install it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)  using `brew install cpanminus`.

After installing cpanminus, try this:

```
sudo cpanm Net::SMTP::SSL
```

Comment: i ran the following:
` sudo -H cpan -fi IO::Socket::SSL` then
` sudo -H perl -MCPAN -e '$ENV{FTP_PASSIVE} = 1; install CPAN'`
but I am still out of luck

Comment: tried cpanm 
! Finding Net::SMPT::SSL on cpanmetadb failed.
! Finding Net::SMPT::SSL () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Net::SMPT::SSL

Comment: If I manually copy Net/SMTP/SSL.pm to the directories in the above error message will that help, so far I have copied to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/` but still I am getting the same error, Do i have to restart the terminal ?

Comment: Hm... Work for me: cpanm Net::SMTP::SSL
--> Working on Net::SMTP::SSL
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CW/CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01 ... OK
Building and testing Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01 ... OK
Successfully installed Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01
1 distribution installed

Comment: You need root access for this action

Comment: yes i manually copied the downloaded SSL.pm to all the directories worked, downloaded from metacpan